# How and where does drupal call Drupal.behaviors.password attach method?

Tags: javascript

I am experiencing a bug in my setup. The symptom is, that the translate variable in Drupal.behaviors.password in core module user/user.js populated from the passed in settings (settings.password) is undefined and hence the password strength checker is not displayed. Whats worse, is that any other javascript on the user edit page for instance fails due to the javascript error.

Can anyone point me in the direction as to where drupal actually calls the Drupal.behaviors.password.attach?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's invoked anywhere that `Drupal.attachBehaviors` is called. Which could be from any number of different places

Comment: Thanks Clive, I just figured it out aswell :-) I will try to trace my phenomenon further and hopefully be able to keep this updated with my findings.